# Method Parameters to String

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

1) I have a method

```
def self.createobj(api_key, amnt, commentstr, orderid, order_creation_date, orderfullfilmentdate)  
.....
end
```

2) I want to create a error_str of all the parameters passed to this function ...

2.1) Something like

```
errorstr = "api_key: " + api_key.to_s + " amnt: " + amnt.to_s + " commentstr: " + commentstr.to_s + " orderid: " + orderid.to_s + " order_creation_date: " + order_creation_date.to_s + " orderfullfilmentdate: " + orderfullfilmentdate.to_s
```

2.2) So I created another method

```
def self.get_params_str(a)
    str = ""
    a.each do |a|
      str = str + a.to_s
    end
    return str
end
```

2.3) So I call this new method from createobj. Something like

```
def self.createobj(api_key, amnt, commentstr, orderid, order_creation_date, orderfullfilmentdate)  
errorstr = get_params_str(args)
.....
end
```

3) But I get error undefined local variable or method `args' for #. Shouldn't args have all parameters?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` would only contain the parameters if your method definition was something like `def self.createobj(*args)`. Without that `args` isn't defined.

You will need to manually pass all of the parameters to `get_params_str`. You will need to pass them as an array, i.e `get_params_str([api_key, amnt, commentstr, ...])` unless you change `get_params_str`'s method signature to `def self.get_params_str(*a)` (which puts all of the parameters passed to `get_params_str` into a single array`).

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do (trying to use a magic var called args that will hold all of the arguments) doesn't work in this way in Ruby.

A method can have optional args:

```
def my_method(*args)
  ....
  # the array args will have 0 or more elements, depending on how many
  # were in the method invocation.
end
```

But if a method has specific (required) args, as in your example, then there is no other way to get at them.

**Added** If you're willing to change the definition of your method to use the work-around for named arguments, then the args will arrive as an associative array and you can then send them to your `get_params_string`

Or better, redefine your `get_params_string` to take a variable arg list

```
def self.get_params_str(*a)
  str = ""
  a.each do |a|
    str = str + a.to_s
  end
  return str
end  

# Then call it from your main method:
def self.createobj(api_key, amnt, commentstr, orderid, 
                   order_creation_date, orderfullfilmentdate)  
  errorstr = get_params_str(api_key, amnt, commentstr, orderid, 
                   order_creation_date, orderfullfilmentdate)
  .....
end
```

**See a useful [post](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/method-arguments-in-ruby/)**

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other responses there's no available variable like `args` that provides the names of the arguments for the method, however if you're on Ruby 1.9.2 (I can't confirm if exist on 1.9.1 as well) you have the method `parameters` so you can do something like this:

```
def foo(a, b, c)
    errorstr = method(:foo).parameters.map{|p| "#{p.last}: #{eval p.last.to_s}" }.join(', ')
    puts errorstr
end

foo(1, 2, 3) #=> a: 1, b: 2, c: 3
```

Comment: +1 So `parameters` is a reflection of the named parameters? Clever.

Comment: I don't know the extent of `parameters` but for example if you try it on `def test(a, *b, &blk) ; end` you will get `[[:req, :a], [:rest, :b], [:block, :blk]]` so not only it gives you the name as a symbol but also tell you if it's required, block, etc.